# Move columns from a data frame below other columns in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 4 columns and 20 rows. I would like to move the last two columns to be below the other two, resulting in 2 columns and 40 rows. Is there any function in R so that I can select as argument the value of columns I want to move (2) without being manually? I ask this because I need it in a for loop. Thanks.

Comment: yes, `rbind` i.e. `rbind(df1[1:2], setNames(df1[3:4], names(df1)[1:2]))`

Comment: Thanks, Akrun! What if I want to move each column down only the first column?

Comment: Then, you can do `data.frame(col1 = unlist(df1))` (assuming that you want a single column data.frame)

Comment: Perfect. But is there any way to keep line names? I used rownames (df2) <- rep (rownames (df1), colnames (df1)) but the names cannot be duplicated.

Comment: I posted as a solution to clarify

Answer (score 2):

We can use `use.names = FALSE` in `unlist`

```
df2 <- data.frame(col1 = unlist(df1, use.names = FALSE))
```

if needed, assign the rownames to `NULL`

```
row.names(df2) <- NULL
```

---

For the first case, `rbind` the subset of columns after making the column names same as the first 2 columns

```
rbind(df1[1:2], setNames(df1[3:4], names(df1)[1:2]))
```